# React renderIntoDocument() returns null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I have a tests case which uses react-dom 16.8
`const mockDOM = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(Component()` returns null. But in react-dom 16.7 it is working fine. Any fixes for that? Component is written using Class not function

Seems like the method implementation has changed